# purpose of the IIFE in a codility equi 100% answer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, callback, logic, iife

```
"use strict";

function solution(dataArray) {
  var total = function (array) {
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    var sum = 0;
    while (--arrayLength > -1) {
      sum += array[arrayLength];
    }
    return sum;
  }(dataArray);
  var eq = -1;
  var arrayLength = dataArray.length;
  var Lsum = 0;
  var Rsum = 0;
  dataArray.forEach(function (number, index) {
    Rsum = total - Lsum - number;
    if (Rsum === Lsum) {
      /* in fact no need to continue, should terminate here. */
      eq = index;
    }
    Lsum += number;
  });
  return eq;
}

console.log(solution(  [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]));
```

I do not understand the purpose of having `}(dataArray)` as iife, isn't it just an array that I could have done just reference `dataArray`directly? I see no special effect on the function anywhere, but without it, Codility actually fails it. Why?

What I tried :

```
var total = function (dataArray) {
    var arrayLength = dataArray.length;
    var sum = 0;
    while (--arrayLength > -1) {
      sum += dataArray[arrayLength];
    }
    return sum;
  };
```

Take it here : https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of a purpose in it, other than structuring the code (so that the `solution` function begins with an array of array declarations with initialisers.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at omitting the IIFE, so we can tell where you made a lapse (that caused the different outcome).